# C++ Linked Lists with Multi-Files

Tags: c++, file, linked-list

I am a bit new to using multi-files. I have this very simple code for a linked list, but when I debug, it "stops working".

This problem has occured with me several times before. I want to know is there something wrong with my "linked list" code? Or is something wrong with the multi-files organization?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

======================================

```
//linkedListMAIN.cpp

#include "linkedlist.cpp"

void main()
{
linkList<int> l;

l.append(5);
l.traverse();
}
```

======================================

```
//linkedList.h    

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class linkList
{
private:
struct node
{
    T data;
    node *next;
};
node *head;
node *tail;
int noOfEl;
public:
linkList()
{
    noOfEl = 0;
    head=tail=NULL;
}

void traverse();
int length();
void insertAt(T, int);
T delAt(int);
void append(T);
void clear();
};
```

======================================

```
//linkedList.cpp    
#include "linkedlist.h"

template <class T>
void linkList<T>:: traverse()
{
node<T> *current=head;

if(head == NULL)
{
    cout<<"List empty."<<endl;
}

while(current != NULL)
{
    cout<<current->data;
    current = current->next;
}
}


template <class T>
void linkList<T>::append(T data)
{
node< *newNode= new node;

newNode->next = NULL;
tail->next = newNode;
tail = newNode;

noOfEl++;  
 }
```

Comment: include "linkedlist.h" in main

Comment: Number of `new` is 1, number of `delete` is 0. Something goes wrong!

Comment: Is this a learning exercise? Otherwise use std:list.

Comment: please indent your code for better readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not include the `.cpp` in inkedListMAIN.cpp but the header (`.h`). Also unless you are using `c++11` you will have to put the class definition of templated classes in the header.

Comment: I do have the class definition in  the header.

Comment: No. You have the class **declaration** in the header. This is enough for regular classes bit for templated ones you have to put the definition there too.